# PostgreSQL JSON query nested issues

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have this JSON record. The field is called 'content'. As you can see, there is a 'products' field. I have been trying to list the product records but it is giving me null.
I came across this article (https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-use-the-postgresql-json-query-1059) and other queries here at StackOverflow and it is still not working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: `products` is ARRAY. It can have many items. So, which item you want to show as name?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_array_elements` to extract the array from JSON data structures.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aaa9fa1ec339d430ba8e010611563509)

```sql
select
  of.content ->> 'code' as offer_code,
  of.content ->> 'name' as offer_name,
  e.value ->> 'name' as name,
  e.value ->> 'type' as type
from
  offer_audit of
  cross join json_array_elements(of.content -> 'products') e
where
  id = 2;
```